# Recursively remove extension from all files with specific extension

Tags: bash, ubuntu, rename, mv

I have a directory with a bunch of subdirectories with a bunch of files with the extension `.no_sub`.

I want to rename every file with extension `.no_sub` to the same name with `.no_sub` removed.

So `foo.no_sub` -> `foo`.

Can I do this in Bash? (I am on Ubuntu 20.04)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the power of your shell to get all files, then use the usual tools to rename them

```bsh
shopt -s nullglob ## as recommended and explained in the comments
shopt -s globstar
shopt -s dotglob
for fname in **/*.no_sub ; do
  mv -- "${fname}" "${fname%.no_sub}"
done
```

Here,

- `shopt -s globstar` enables `**` as a recursive glob
- `shopt -s dotglob` enables finding `.*.no_sub`
- The `for` loop is a special-character-safe way to go through all files ([don't ever parse `ls` for that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead))
- The `mv` syntax is `mv source target`;
- I'm sometimes overly careful, but I also like `${fname}` better than just `$fname`, because there can't be a variable name confusion. It just expands to the content of the variable `fname`, i.e. to the current file
- The variable expansion `${variable%pattern}` expands to the variable content, but reduced by the suffix pattern `pattern`

Comment: may want to use `./**/*.no_sub` as the glob, and/or use `--` with `mv` to stop any filenames starting with dashes from looking like options to `mv`. Also, maybe `mv -n` to not overwrite the target file if it exists (or not, depends on what you want).

Comment: thanks for the safety edit, @ilkkachu !! yeah, files called `-rf` can be .. tricky.

Comment: Use `shopt -s nullglob` as well, just in case there are no `.no_sub` files. That will prevent you from calling `mv -- "**/*.no_sub" "**/*"`, which could be disastrous if `**/*` expands to something that ends in a valid directory name.

Comment: @chepner, `nullglob` is definitely a good idea when using `for` over a glob, but as long as the expansions are in quotes, they globs shouldn't expand again, you'd only get problems for a file literally called `**/*.no_sub`.

Comment: Oh, right; I overlooked the quoting. So `nullglob` would just prevent a call to `mv` that's doomed to return an error (unless there really is a file named `**/*.no_sub`, which would then be renamed `**/*` :) ).

Comment: @chepner, which could then trash a file called `**/*`, yes :) But in any case, `nullglob` should be used even if only for correctness. Also `dotglob`, if you want to catch files like `dir/.dotfile.no_sub`, or even `.dotdir/file.no_sub`.

Comment: there can't be `**/*.no_sub` because otherwise  match wouldn't be empty. So it seems it's actually safe always

Answer (score 15):

Using standard `find`, `sh`, and `mv`:

```bsh
find . -type f -name '*.no_sub' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        mv -- "$pathname" "${pathname%.no_sub}"
    done' sh {} +
```

This finds any regular file with a name that ends in the string `.no_sub`, in or below the current directory.  For batches of these pathnames, a short in-line shell script is called.  This `sh -c` script iterates over the given batch of pathnames and renames each of them by removing the `.no_sub` filename suffix.  The removal of the filename suffix is done using the standard `${variable%suffix}` parameter expansion.

No check is made for filename collisions.

This is *similar* to [the solution provided by Marcus Müller](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/658925/116858) in that the renaming of an individual file happens in an identical way, but uses `find` to generate the list of pathnames for the loop in a way that will pick up hidden names and includes an explicit file type filter to iterate over regular files only.

See also: [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

---

Since we know that each filename given to the inline script ends with `.no_sub`, we may avoid repeating `.no_sub` in there if we want to:

```bsh
find . -type f -name '*.no_sub' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        mv -- "$pathname" "${pathname%.*}"
    done' sh {} +
```

Comment: nice. especially the checking for plain-file-ness is a good idea!

Answer (score 11):

You can do this with `find` and `xargs`:

```
find . -name '*.nosub' -print0 | xargs -0 rename .nosub ""
```

The `-print0` option to `find` and the `-0` option of `xargs` are there to correctly handle filenames with spaces. The `rename` command is the one provided by the `util-linux` package.

Comment: This would remove the first `.nosub` substring from a filename, renaming `somefile.nosub.abc.nosub` into `somefile.abc.nosub`.

Comment: That's true, but at least in my experience it's practically unlikely. If you're not confident about spurious matches, I guess use one of the other solutions. As @cas demonstrates, it's easier to protect against this using the Perl rename utility.

Answer (score 3):

Using the perl `rename` utility (aka `prename`, `file-rename`, `perl-rename` on various different distros):

```
find . -type f -name '*.no_sub' -print0 |
  rename -0 's/\.no_sub$//'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using POSIX `find`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.no_sub' \
-exec perl -le '
  rename $_, s/\.no_sub$//r
    for @ARGV;
' {} +;
```

We look for regular files whose Names end with `.no_sub` and place the names in a bunch on the commandline of `perl`.

Perl then invokes it's built-in rename command and removes the trailing extension .no_sub, in effect, moving the file.

Answer (score 2):

No need for loops, just use the `rename` utility from the [util-linux package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/util-linux).

```
$ /usr/bin/rename.ul '.no_sub' '' *.no_sub
```

See the [rename man page](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/util-linux/rename.ul.1.en.html), especially the last, "shortening" example in the EXAMPLES section.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to [Kusalananda's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/658953/245871), but this will process the file one by one and without using a loop.

```bsh
find . -type f -name '*.no_sub' -exec sh -c 'mv -- "$1" "${1%.no_sub}"' sh {} \;
```